# I want to implement a swap method in my class using templated swap

Tags: c++

I have a class with only one member which is a vector.

```
class myClass{
private:
    vector<double> vector_member;
public:
    method1();
    method2();
    ...
}
```

I want to implement a swap method in this class with a templated swap.
I'm learning the copy-swap idiom right now, the use of the swap method is to help with the operator =.
What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
void Polynomial :: swap(Polynomial& p){
    std::swap(this.vector_member, p.vector_member)
}
```

I read about "swap" at here, [swap Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/), at the beginning it says:
The behavior of this function template `std::swap` is equivalent to:

```
template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
{
  T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}
```

But why can't I use it in my method? Or am I misunderstanding anything here?

Comment: Have you included the `algorithm`?

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic It's actually in `<utility>` since C++11.

Comment: Note, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is a much better reference.

Comment: @IlCapitano Thanks this fix it.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. Much better.

Comment: `this.vector_member` should be `this->vector_member`.

Comment: `this.vector_memeber` should be `vector_member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely missing an `#include` for the header file that `std::swap()` is defined in.

Prior to C++11, `std::swap()` is in `<algorithm>`.  In C++11 and later, it is in `<utility>` instead.

```cpp
#include <utility> // or <algorithm>

void Polynomial :: swap(Polynomial& p){
    std::swap(vector_member, p.vector_member);
}
```

That being said, [`std::vector` has its own `swap()` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap).  `std::swap()` is simply specialized for `std::vector` to call `std::vector::swap()`, so you can just call it directly yourself and not use `std::swap` at all:

```cpp
void Polynomial::swap(Polynomial& p){
    vector_member.swap(p.vector_member);
}
```

Comment: The advantage of using `using std::swap;swap(vector_member, p.vector_member);` is that if you change the type of `vector_member` it should still work without needing to modify any code. Using `vector_member.swap()` directly means that you need to manually fix the call when changing type and the new type does not have `swap()` method.